# How to change multiple div classes at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have 2 li's that are clickable. On mouse click, I would like to change the class of 10 other divs on the page (not any of the divs being clicked on).

Here is the interaction I'm looking for:

-Clicking the first li sets the class of 10 divs to "class1". (these classes are already set by default)

-Clicking the second li changes the same 10 classes to "class2"

-Toggle back and fourth

How is this done?

Comment: Are you using a framework like jQuery?

Comment: I want to be able to click on "Relative" to apply the class "row1". Click on "Absolute" to apply the class "row1A".


<div id="toggle">
        <div class="formRow">
          <div class="formFieldWidgets">
            <ul class="segmentControl">
              <li id="relative" class="selected">Relative</li>
              <li id="absolute">Absolute</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

Comment: Here's the code for the div who's class I am trying to change:

<div id="graphWrap"><a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>
     <div class="row1" id="graph1">
          <div id="candleCircle"></div>
          <div id="candleWick"></div>
          <div id="candleBody"></div>
     </div>
     </a>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/cJp5D/)

Comment: Your example is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks so much for sharing. I tried applying it to my page but doesn't work for me. Does it matter if "class1" and "class2" are deep inside layers and layers of divs? See my code above.

Answer (score 3):

You should give some code example.
If I were you I would use jQuery. There are click, toggle events and many selectors to choose those divs.

The example:

```
$("li:first").click(function() {
    $("div").setClass("class1");
});
$("li:eq(1)").click(function() {
    $("div").setClass("class2");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. See my tow comments above for the code. I am open to using jQuery or whatever works. Please share example code of how I should use it in my page.

Answer (score 0):

the answer provided by `Wojciech` is good and will work. But what if you want to add 100 clickable items? I prefer a methodology that is more expandable and generalized for broader use (not to mention more compact in size).

**Alterative #1**

you could use the jQuery `index()` function to find out the index of the clicked item and then apply the class that way...

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var index = $('li').index($(this))+1;
    $("div").setClass("class" + index);
});
```

**Alterative #2**

you can add a custom attribute to your `<li>` items

```
<li classToApply="class1">First Clickable Item</li>
<li classToApply="class2">Second Clickable Item</li>

$('li').click(function(){
    $("div").setClass($(this).attr('classToApply'));
});
```

**Worth Mentioning**

Both my example and the one provided by `Wojciech` require [The jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks Dutchie432, but how to I setup the code in the html? What code to I apply to the li's to get this to work?